# Solr: how to specify a schema during JSON and CSV import?

Tags: json, csv, solr

I'm new to Solr and I'm trying to test its functionalities. I come from RDBMS world and was wondering how Solr would perform with my data.

I created a new core:

`$ bin/solr create -c test`

and successfully loaded a JSON file using:

`$ bin/post -c test file.json`

The first record of `file.json` looks like this:

`{"attr":"01234"}`

but Solr stores it as:

`{"attr":1234}`

I began defining a Data Import Handler following [this tutorial (Youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VkFQTqrRYo) in order to correctly store my data, and found that JSON can't be processed by DIH. I'm stuck at the definition of `data-config.xml` because the tutorial treats XML files using the `XPathEntityProcessor` but can't find a JSON or even a CSV processor (I can easily retrieve a CSV version of `file.json`, so loading a CSV or a JSON is the same for me). The official documentation is a bit of a mess and doesn't provide many useful examples. The solely processors that probably treat JSON and CSV documents are `LineEntityProcessor` and `PlainTextEntityProcessor` ( [Official Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-EntityProcessors)).

[This other link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor) from the Solr Wiki states:

> **Goals**
>
> > ...
> >
> > Make it possible to plugin any kind of datasource (ftp,scp etc) and any other format of user choice (**JSON**,**csv** etc)

so I guess it is really possible, but HOW?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798194/solr-how-to-import-json-files-using-dataconfig) posted in 2014 that no one answered here, so was wondering if in 2016, with the newer versions of Solar, there is a well known solution to this problem.

So the question is: how to import JSON and CSV documents using a specific data schema?

### **UPDATE**

Executing `http://localhost:8983/solr/test/dihupdate?command=full-import` doesn't trigger any error but doesn't load any document. Here are the various xml files located in the core directory:

**`solrconfig.xml`**

```
...
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory" />
...
<requestHandler name="/dihupdate" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
...
```

**`schema.xml`**

```
...
<field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="attr1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="attr2" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
<field name="attr3" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="attr4" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
...
```

**`data-config.xml`**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="f" processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
                fileName="test.json"
                rootEntity="false"
                dataSource="null"
                recursive="true"
                baseDir="/path/to/data/"/>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Solr distribution, there is a films example (in **example/films**) that shows how to index JSON and takes advantage of both exact field definitions and type auto-detect. The instructions (**README.txt**) include the results you will see if you forget to do one of the steps as well.

I suggest you experiment with that and then apply that knowledge to your own use case.

Comment: I achieved this by adding the field definition via `{"add-field":{...}}` as stated in the `README.txt` file. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Defining the schema is either done in `schema.xml` in your `conf` directory - this is the [traditional way of setting up the expected format for documents (Defining Fields)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields). If you're using the "Managed Schema" mode which is the current default, you'll have to [switch to using the classic schema factory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig). You can then define the fields in your `schema.xml` by following the example schema, or any resource available on the web that describes how the schema.xml file is structured (you define a field type and then fields that uses that field type).

The other option is the managed schema - this is the default in the most recent releases, and this schema is manipulated through the API that Solr offers. On startup it reads the initial schema from schema.xml (if present), but after that you'll have to modify it through the API or the Admin interface. This API is described (with examples) at the [Schema API page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API) in the Solr guide.

Using a StrField (which ìs what the field type `string` uses) to store `012345` would result in Solr storing just the literal value, `012345`, without converting it to an integer. That's probably a good place to start.

Comment: I followed your indication but I have to specifiy somewhere the location of JSON/CSV data. I updated my question with the various XML parameters. Thank you

Comment: If you have JSON data, you can submit that directly to the update handler as long as it matches the JSON format Solr expects, and it matches the schema you have defined.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do as an alternative way to the missing processor, but I'm encountering this error: `{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":4},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Unknown command 'id' at [5]","code":400}}`. The JSON syntax is correct (the file is generated by PostgreSQL) and the previous rows don't trigger that error.. The row that generates the error is `{"id":400,...}` and doesn't have nested attributes.

Comment: Which version of Solr? The version might assume that the document is wrapped in a {'add': ... } element. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates

Comment: It's version 6.2.1 and I'm trying to execute this command: `curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/path/to/file.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'`. If I try to execute the command that this morning worked (you can see it in my original question: `bin/post -c test file.json`), it throws the following error: `... {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":40},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"This IndexSchema is not mutable.","code":400}} ...`

Comment: In `schema.xml` I set `<field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />` and `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`. For what I can understand, it's necessary to have a index in Solr, or not?

Comment: Following @Alexandre Rafalovitch suggestion, I used the API and the managed schema in order to add the fields definition before importing the data. Thank you for your help, I've learned a lot of new things :)